# factoring left side to product with 3 terms

Tags: exponentiation, factoring

I want to solve the following problem:

$2x^3 +x^2 -50x = 25$

I first subtracted both sides by 25:

$2x^3 +x^2 -50x -25 = 0$

But then I got stuck, so I put in the problem in wolframalpha to see what it recommends

Wolfram solves the problem by doing what I did and then factor the left side to a product of 4:

$(x - 5)(x + 5)(2x + 1) = 0$

My problem with this is, how am I supposed to come to that conclusion without using a computer? I seems like it would take a lot of trial and error to get the result unless there exists some algorithm I don't know of.

So my question is: What is the process of factoring $2x^3 +x^2 -50x -25 = 0$ into $(x - 5)(x + 5)(2x + 1) = 0$? Or is there another way which is easier?

Thank you!

Comment: See,the best thing to do is to try and substitute factors of $25$ into the expression, and see when you get zero. If $f(x) =0$, then $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Comment: Well, finding roots to general polynomials can be difficult.  In this case, [The Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) works.  This method finds all rational roots (assuming, as here, that the coefficients are all integers).

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)? Basically, it says that if a polynomial has any rational roots, they will be a factor of the constant divided by a factor of the leading coefficient. There are [other ways to find roots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm), but they usually require some calculus. There is also a [closed form equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) for the roots of a third degree polynomial, but no one ever uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that 
\begin{equation}\label{eq24}
\begin{split}
2x^3 + x^2 -50x - 25
&=
(2x^3  -50x) + [x^2 - 25]
\\&=
2x(x^2  -25) + [x^2 - 25]
\\&=
(x^2  -25)(2x - 1)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $x^2 - 25 = (x-5)(x+5)$